# How to $broadcast using AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `$broadcast` event its working from parent controller but i don't see object coming in child controller i am not sure what i am implementing wrong.

How can i achieve this task using angularJs event ?

parentCtrl.js

```
$scope.$broadcast('assessmentData',$scope.RiskAssessDTO);
```

childCtrl.js

```
if ($stateParams.assessmentId) {
    $scope.$on('assessmentData', function(s, assessmentData) {
        var assessmentData = assessmentData;
        console.log('assessmentData', assessmentData);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is the child loaded and is the if condition true BEFORE you attempt to broadcast?

Comment: yes child is loaded and if condition satisfy

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use $broadcast you should use $rootScope.

```
$scope.startScanner = function() {

    $rootScope.$broadcast('scanner-started');
}
```

And then to receive, use the $scope of your controller:

```
$scope.$on('scanner-started', function(event, args) {

    // do what you want to do
});
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on

Regards,

Comment: This isn't necessarily correct. You only NEED to use `$rootScope` if emitting alongside the root scope to deal with handlers registered at that level.  In this case, broadcasting from the `$rootScope` may actually ***mask*** scoping issues where your scopes aren't at the levels you think they are at.